# default textsize in sybase

Tags: sybase

the default textsize in sybase is 32768.
i can see this when i login to sybase and type:

```
1> select @@textsize
2> go

 ----------- 
       32768 

(1 row affected)
```

when i did some googling i got the info that using the set command i can change the default textsize to my own value

```
1> set textsize 42768
2> go
1> select @@textsize
2> go

 ----------- 
       42768 

(1 row affected)
```

But my problem here is this is not persisting.
as soon as i close the session,it sets back to 32768.

does anybody know how could i change the default textsize permanently in sybase.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to persist this it must be set within each session as required. There is no corresponding parameter for sp_configure.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1570/html/sag1/X68714.htm

If it's set within a stored procedure, the setting lasts for the stored procedure's scope.

```
select @@textsize
go
create procedure test_textsize as
set textsize 123456
select @@textsize
go
exec test_textsize
go
select @@textsize
go
```

Result

```
 session_textsize 
 ---------------- 
            32768 

(1 row affected)
 proc_textsize 
 ------------- 
        123456 

(1 row affected)
(return status = 0)
 session_textsize 
 ---------------- 
            32768 

(1 row affected)
```

**Update for Sybase ASE 16**

This can be achieved using a login trigger in the login's default database.

```
create procedure login_trigger as
set textsize 12345
go
```

Add the login trigger to the user account.

```
sp_modifylogin a_login, "login script", login_trigger
go
```

Test in another isql session:

```
$ isql -U a_login -S SOME_ASE
Password: 
1> select @@textsize
2> go

 ----------- 
       12345 

(1 row affected)
1>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [HERE](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/32745;pt=33180)!

---

The set textsize command specifies the limit, in bytes, of the text or image data to be returned with a select statement. For example, this command sets the limit on text or image data returned with a select statement to 100 bytes:

```
set textsize 100
```

The current setting is stored in the @@textsize global variable. **The default setting is controlled by the client program.** To reset the default, issue:

```
set textsize 0
```

---

**I think the default value is configured when configuring the server.**

Comment: Sorry, although I've searched a lot, I'm not 100% certain.